# Variation in deathstalker scorpion

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I recently encountered a (probable) [deathstalker scorpion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathstalker) in the Negev desert in Israel:

[image]

However, when trying to identify this species I found that in many/most photos of the yellow scorpion the final segment before the stinger was dark or even black (see the [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathstalker) for examples) i.e., not yellow, as shown in the photo.

Is a black/dark pre-stinger segment an indication of some sort (perhaps venom?), or is it an indication of a separate species, or other? Clarification on this matter is most welcome.

---

Update - I contacted an Israeli PhD from Haifa University who wrote the following:

"...looks like *Andrtoctonus amareuxi* (also referred in the past as *Andrtoctonus amareuxi hebraeus*, Israeli fat-tailed scorpion (קטלן עברי)
the genus common name is fat-tailed scorpion... The color of the last segment of the abdomen before the stinger is not a very good sign alone for species identification, as it is variable in the population and also found in at least 2 other genera/species (in the genus *Buthus* and in some species of the genus *Compsobuthus*). Anyway for sure it is not the deathstalker which is easily identified by a marking on the prosoma, behind the central eyes, that looks like a lyre  and the ridges on the abdomen..."

Comment: The scorpion in question appears to be Buthacus leptochelys, and is not a Leiurus sp.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Israeli Scorpions Field Guide, deathstalkers can have also pale metasomal segment V, so a black one isn't a sure identification sign although it is very common among deathstalkers. The characteristic of the Israeli deathstalker are 5 ridges along its back. The species of deathstalker in the Negev (and Israel) is *Leiurus hebraeus*.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found an official reference, just a mention that the metasomal segment V can be pale in some adults.

Perhaps after molting the colour is different?

Also, dont know if it is Leiurus quinquestriatus, L. hebraeus, or L. abdullahbayrami

I see picture with the same pale coloration at sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-science‌​s/…